# Error while executing,"To test Glance, upload the “cirros cloud image” directly from the internet"

Tags: openstack

Tried executing the same query given:

```
glance image-create --name OS4Y_Cirros --is-public true --container-format bare --disk-format qcow2 --location https://launchpad.net/cirros/trunk/0.3.0/+download/cirros-0.3.0-x86_64-disk.img
```

Error Received:

```
Error communicating with http://192.168.1.51:9292 [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```

Comment: 192.168.* is a local network address, not an internet location.

Comment: 192.168.x.x and 10.x.x.x fall in private network addresses. What about it? What are you implying?

Comment: You're sending a request to `launchpad.net`, but getting an error back from 192.*, suggesting that your request is being somehow redirected to your local network (a proxy perhaps) rather than reaching the target site, and is thus failing.

Answer (score 0):

**Command**: glance image-create --name OS4Y_Cirros --is-public true --container-format bare --disk-format qcow2 --location https://launchpad.net/cirros/trunk/0.3.0/+download/cirros-0.3.0-x86_64-disk.img

**Error**:Error communicating with [a link]h(ttp://192.168.1.51:9292)! [Errno 110] Connection timed out

**Solution**: Change the external host ip address in keystone_basic.sh to 192.168.100.51